# date picker value getting added to last position of dynamically inflated edittext

Tags: android

I'm creating a layout which contains DOB_ Edittext.

I'm adding layout in loop dynamically depending on the count, now the problem is when I am trying to add the value from date picker , the value always gets added to last position in edittext in the layout

Any help is appreciated :)

```
    for(int children = 0; children<Integer.parseInt(childrentCount)  ; children++){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_layout,null);

                  DOB_ = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.dob);
        final int finalChildren = children;
        DOB_.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                DOB_.setTag(finalChildren);
                DOB_.setSelection(finalChildren);
                setCanlenderDate();

             //   DOB_.requestFocusFromTouch();
            }
        });

        if (child_no<=0){
            DOB_.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }



        heading_text.setText("Children "+(children+1));
        whole_layout.addView(view);
        whole_layout.clearFocus();
    }

  private void setCanlenderDate() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(PassengerDetails.this, this,
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    String[] MONTHS = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};


    DOB_.setText(i2 + "-" + i1 + 1 + "-" + i); // problem is here , the edittext is holding last position of inflated view

}
```

Comment: Waaay too much code. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question and trim your code down to a [mcve].

Comment: i reduced to code minimum now :P , let me know if you can give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one solution first you need to add the tag to DOB and make it locally

```
EditText DOB_ = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.dob);
DOB_.setTag(children);  // it is the position of the view.
```

Now when you click on the DOB_ then get the tag and store in a global variable

```
 int selectedPos;

DOB_.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
             .
             .
             .
             selectedPos = DOB_.getTag();
             setCanlenderDate();

             //   DOB_.requestFocusFromTouch();
            }
        });
```

And then in the last function

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    String[] MONTHS = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

View view = whole_layout.getChildAt(selectedPos);
EditText DOB_ = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.dob);

    DOB_.setText(i2 + "-" + i1 + 1 + "-" + i); // problem is here , the edittext is holding last position of inflated view

}
```

Comment: I am getting crash :
07-23 13:15:42.851  9781  9781 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.destinationtrip.myapplication, PID: 9781
07-23 13:15:42.851  9781  9781 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
07-23 13:15:42.851  9781  9781 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.example.destinationtrip.myapplication.PassengerDetails.onDateSet(PassengerDetails.java:1099)

Comment: Please add the crash from logcat

Comment: Here you go :
com.example.destinationtrip.myapplication, PID: 9781 07-23 13:15:42.851 9781 9781 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference 07-23 13:15:42.851 9781 9781 E AndroidRuntime: at com.example.destinationtrip.myapplication.PassengerDetails.onDateSet(PassengerDetails.java:1099) –

Comment: You need to check here ** selectedPos = DOB_.getTag();** is this position same on which you clicked @PriyankaSN

Comment: DOB_ itself is null